# При передаче selectedItems в конструктор класса, передается null

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблемка, пытаюсь передать значения в другой класс, но передает null, хотя условие срабатывает. Также с помощью откладки, я посмотрел, что значения есть, но параметр конструктора содержить null

условие, при котором передается значение:

```
if (product.lstbx.SelectedItems != null)
            {
                FrameForOrder.Navigate(new ViewCreateOrder(product.lstbxProduct.SelectedItems as DataView));
            }
```

конструктор другого класса:

```
 public ViewCreateOrder(DataView dataView)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   lstbx.ItemsSource = dataView;
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что в SelectedItems лежит DataView? as допускает, что будет null, если тип, к которому вы его хотите скастовать будет не тот

Comment: @LiptonDev вот оно как....а можете подсказать какой тип лучше юзать? я пробовал IList<T>, но он ругался, есть варианты? мб можно как-то преобразовать в `DataView`?

Comment: В SelectedItem(s) лежит тот тип, который вы туда и положите. Если положите DataView - заберет DataView, но обычно туда складывают какие-то простые модели данных. У вас в listBox положен DataView, в SelectedItem(s) будет какая-то его строка (Row). С DataView очень давно дел не имел, поэтому загадывать не буду, лучше уйдите от DataView.

Comment: @LiptonDev я пользуюсь ado.net и уйти пока что будет проблематично) спасибо за совет

Comment: Смотрите в сторону EF (Core), а там дальше будет проще

Comment: Потому что product.lstbxProduct.SelectedItems это не DataView, поэтому as возвращает null. Смотрите в отладчике, что там, ставьте точку останова. А можете не париться и просто передать как object или IEnumerable не обобщенный